# how to configure isc dchp server with different subnets with different wl-access points

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, dhcp

I have two different subnets in the same layer 2.

- 192.168.1.*
- 192.168.2.*

add. two gateways for access to the internet

- 192.168.1.1
- 192.168.2.1

add. two wl access points

- 192.168.1.2
- 192.168.2.1 (the same unit like for the gateway)

Now I try to configure a dhcp server to mange my network (server: 192.168.1.10).

My most important requirement is send the right network configuration based on the subnet and the connected wl-access point.
E.g. if a device connect to the wl-access point 192.168.1.2 it should receive the ip (192.168.1.xy) and the gateway for the correspond subnet (192.168.1.1).

The other requirement is one of the subnet (192.168.2.*) should receive all wired connect (unknown) devices and the subnet (192.168.1.*) all known wired devices. To support one of them is no problem, but both at the same ?

I have one unmanged switch and a server with two physical network interfaces (etho, eth1)

It's even possible to achieve my requirements with the given hardware?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible. In your setup there's no way for your centralized DHCP server to know which AP or switch a given DHCP client is connected to, so there's no way for it to give out different addresses based on where the client is connecting.

Comment: Thanks a lot. These statement save a lot of investigation time. Now i gona split these subnets physical (add an second switch) and gona implement a internal gateway between them .